# Dojo JsonRestStore and ClientFilter never updates from server

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a Dojo Datagrid bound to a JsonRestStore with ClientFilter enabled.
The behaviour I want:

> Every time I call filter on the DataGrid, the store should perform the
>   query locally and update the grid. Meanwhile it should also send the
>   same query to the server, adding the data it receives to the client
>   filtered data.

The documentation of ClientFilter seems to say this is how its supposed to work.
This is the behaviour I get:

> The datagrid loads the data from the server once, according to the
>   initial filter settings. Any further calls to datagrid.filter only
>   filter the data on the client. No more XHR calls to the server are
>   sent.

I have spent hours debugging ClientFilter.js looking for the bug but can't find it. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I want to put this here so hopefully someone looking for similar information doesn't get stuck as well. There are known issues with ClientFilter and JsonRestStore.
Confused with all the old documentation on the internet, I was using dojo.data.JsonRestStore
This is an old and unsupported(?) store. Dojo has now moved to the new ObjectStore API.
The closest store implementing this new API is dojo.store.JsonRest and ClientFilter functionality is provided by dojo.store.Cache

Comment: What I want is, say I am filtering based on date of creation. If I reduce the filter, it should filter on the client side and give it to me, but if I increase the range of the filter, it should get me more results from the server. Isn't that something fairly routine?

Comment: Explaining the use case a little more: I'm filtering on two fields fromDate and toDate. Initially fromDate=2012-01-20 and toDate=2012-01-24 .This gets me the appropriate results from the server. Now if I change fromDate to 2012-01-21, the store filters the dataset on the client and shows the results. This is required behaviour. If I change fromDate to 2012-01-19, the expected behaviour is for the store to ask for more data from the server. Instead, the store merely returns all the data it has in the cache(which doesn't include data for 19th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, in dojox.data.JsonRestStore everything that has been cached remain cached, and you cannot flush an Item or a query, as far as I know. You could try clearCache(), if you rely lightly on caching it might work.
Otherwise, you would have to hack deep into the JRS to achieve a real clearCache depending on your needs.
To achieve something similar to your need, you *might* connect on the filter and issue the very same query on the store with a minor addition like "&date=" + (new Date().toString())
or something like that to force refresh...
Not sure it would totally solve your problem, and it would be kind of defeating the purpose of your cache, except for the fast loading of the first filter.
I am not even sure that forcing the query would update your datagrid... but you can give it a try.

Comment: My idea here is to use the cache to display initial results for every query asap. For this to really help out people, the cache would have to be used heavily, so clearCache is probably not an option.

Comment: Then you might want to try out what I said about connecting to filter and issueing a new fetch adding a date/timestamp param to itso that you load your cache first, then refresh it with the fetch+date, but i never tried that before :)

Comment: I'm not sure that approach will work either because the URL's GET params do change between the two requests(see comment on original question). My problem is not that the browser is caching the response from the server, it is that the store is not attempting to fetch new data from the server(I'm using Firebug to make sure). You think changing the URL would help?

Comment: I think so, because JRS is caching queries, the reason why it never calls the server again... your query has already been cached. Adding a date parameter will make your query change everytime (approximately ^^), and this query will never be cached. The thing is, how to tell the JRS that the new resultSet is the new cache for the old fetch query? I have not dug into that for a long time so i'm not sure about the results and hacks, but i think this is a good start :) If not, you're doomed :P